# How to insert comma after the certain character?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

How can I insert a comma after a certain character but do not insert comma for the last record.

I have data

```
[
{"ID": 12345}
{"ID": 67891}
{"ID": 14785}
]
```

so I am trying to insert a comma after every `}` except the last one.

So the update should be like this:

```
[
{"ID": 12345},
{"ID": 67891},
{"ID": 14785}
]
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: is the `]` on the new line or on the same line?

Comment: In the next line.

Comment: If your end goal is to create valid JSON, then it might be simpler to remove the surrounding brackets and let `jq` construct a new array from the individual objects ex. `sed -e '1d' -e '$d' data | jq -n '[inputs]'`

Comment: Would it not be better to insert the commas while the data is generated, or are you working with a program that generates broken JSON?  The `jo` tool is useful for generating JSON documents in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^{/ { if (lastline ~ "}$") lastline=lastline ","; print lastline; }; '\
'! /^{/ && NR>1 { print lastline; }; { lastline=$0; }; '\
'END { print lastline; }' inputfile
[
{"ID": 12345},
{"ID": 67891},
{"ID": 14785}
]
[
{"ID": 12345},
{"ID": 67891},
{"ID": 14785}
]
```

Comment: Hi Hauke, this also prints a comma after the last `}`

Comment: @Quasímodo Of course, it does. Embarrassing.

Comment: @HaukeLaging : I think if more than one record set [...] present , yours is outputting extra '[' and ']'.Please check.

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar Works with several sets now.

Answer (score 0):

Perl One-liner:

```
$ perl -a -F"\n" -ne 'BEGIN{$/="]";} print $F[0]."\n" if $. == 1; map { ($F[$_] =~ /[\[\]]/)  || ($_ == @F-2) ? print $F[$_]."\n" : print $F[$_].",\n"; } (1 .. @F-1)  ' file
[
{"ID": 12345},
{"ID": 67891},
{"ID": 14785}
]
[
{"ID": 12345},
{"ID": 67891},
{"ID": 67891},
{"ID": 14785}
]
```

Input File:

```
$ cat file
[
{"ID": 12345}
{"ID": 67891}
{"ID": 14785}
]
[
{"ID": 12345}
{"ID": 67891}
{"ID": 67891}
{"ID": 14785}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `tr` and `sed`

```
tr "\n" "|" < file | sed  "s/}|{/},|{/g" | tr "|" "\n" file
```

Or even

```
tr "\n" "|" < file | sed  "s/}|{/},\n{/g; s/|/\n/g"
```

Line length may be limited if you are not using [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html)